# Infragistics, Telerik or devexpress .. which one is better then others?

Tags: .net, controls, telerik, devexpress, infragistics

We are planning to purchase third part controls for Asp.net and WPF both. we short list Infragistics, Telerik, devexpress. But now have to decide that which one to purchase from these three.

I Google about the disadvantages or week points of these controls but I want some solid reason to select one or reject others.

I want to know the users experience about these controls, which could be helpful for me to take decision.

thanks

Comment: Which one has the control(s) you need?

Comment: no... I mean that which controls should I select? are their any disadvantages of these controls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What 3rd Party Controls are .Net Developers using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81787/what-3rd-party-controls-are-net-developers-using)

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Usercontrols telerik devexpress infragistics ComponentOne: who's best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169357/net-usercontrols-telerik-devexpress-infragistics-componentone-whos-best)

Comment: You might consider downloading a free trial of the control packages that you're interested in to get a better feel of the user experience they provide to *you*. If no free trial is offered on the website, you can probably contact sales or support, explain your concerns, and request one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used (and owned subscriptions to) all three.  These days I tend to use DevExpress for Winforms apps and Telerik for ASP.NET, and that is a result of which company had the controls I needed back when I started the projects. Once you have a large app in production you tend to stick with the suite you used.  My experience with Infragistics was back in the VB6 days.

My advice would be to get the free trials and then base your decision on these things:

- a) does the suite offer the controls you need?
- b) how amenable to your  style do you find the public interfaces of their controls?
- c) how well is the suite documented?
- d) how easy is it to find answers/info on the  company's website / online knowledge  base / community forum
- e) how active  are the community forums, and what is  the predominant type of activity  there? you want to find
  people  discussing solutions, not workarounds

Overall, I have liked the Telerik customer experience best.

Answer (score 2):

Working in one of these companies :), I can recommend that you try our controls.  Only your own experience will tell you which Suite meets your requirements better.  If you run into troubles when using our controls, you are always welcome to post your questions to the [support center](http://devexpress.com/support/center).  We will do our best to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I am actively using 3rd party components for over two years now. My suggestion will be Telerik...